# Stack overflow error when deserializing binary file

Tags: java, deserialization, binaryfiles

So i'm trying to save information into an object array list, everything works however, whenever I try to load a previously saved array list I receive a stack overflow error.

I'm guessing I need some sort of counter however, I'm not to familiar with java and how the deserializer works. I've attached my code below - any help would be appreciated.

```
ArrayList<Car> cars = new ArrayList<Car>();

public void addCar
{
     System.out.println("What is the make of the car?");
     String newMake = scan.next();
     System.out.println("What is the model of the car?");
     String newModel = scan.next();
     System.out.println("What year was the car produced?");
     String newYear = scan.next();
     System.out.println("How far has this car traveled?");
     String newOdometer = scan.next();
     cars.add(new Car(newMake, newModel, newYear, newOdometer));   
}

public void openFile()
    {
        Car cars = new Car();
      try {
         FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream("testSave.plzwork");
         ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
            try {
                cars = (Car)in.readObject();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(carClass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
         in.close();
         fileIn.close();
        }
        catch (IOException i) {
         i.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

**EDIT**
Here's the serialising code

```
public void saveFile()
    { 
        try 
        {
            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("testSave.plzwork");
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
            out.writeObject(cars);
            out.close();
            fileOut.close();
            System.out.println("Serialized data is saved");
        } 
        catch (IOException i) {
        i.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
```

**EDIT 2** 
Here's the car class

```
public Car(String year, String odometer, String make, String model)
    {
        this.make = make; 
        this.model = model; 
        this.year = year; 
        this.odometer = odometer; 
    }
```

Here's the error that Netbeans is spitting out

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
>       at java.base/java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.setLength(AbstractStringBuilder.java:277)
>       at java.base/java.lang.StringBuffer.setLength(StringBuffer.java:233)
>       at java.base/java.text.DecimalFormat.expandAffix(DecimalFormat.java:2978)
>       at java.base/java.text.DecimalFormat.expandAffixes(DecimalFormat.java:2946)
>       at java.base/java.text.DecimalFormat.applyPattern(DecimalFormat.java:3632)
>       at java.base/java.text.DecimalFormat.(DecimalFormat.java:466)
>       at java.base/sun.util.locale.provider.NumberFormatProviderImpl.getInstance(NumberFormatProviderImpl.java:187)
>       at java.base/sun.util.locale.provider.NumberFormatProviderImpl.getNumberInstance(NumberFormatProviderImpl.java:151)
>       at java.base/java.text.NumberFormat.getInstance(NumberFormat.java:969)
>       at java.base/java.text.NumberFormat.getInstance(NumberFormat.java:953)
>       at java.base/java.text.NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(NumberFormat.java:518)
>       at java.base/java.util.Scanner.useLocale(Scanner.java:1270)
>       at java.base/java.util.Scanner.(Scanner.java:543)
>       at java.base/java.util.Scanner.(Scanner.java:566)
>       at pkg30000969carsarraylist.Car.(Car.java:29)
>       at pkg30000969carsarraylist.Car.(Car.java:46)
>       at pkg30000969carsarraylist.Car.(Car.java:46)
>       at pkg30000969carsarraylist.Car.(Car.java:46)
>       at pkg30000969carsarraylist.Car.(Car.java:46)
>       at pkg30000969carsarraylist.Car.(Car.java:46)
>       at pkg30000969carsarraylist.Car.(Car.java:46)
>       at pkg30000969carsarraylist.Car.(Car.java:46)
>       at pkg30000969carsarraylist.Car.(Car.java:46)
>       at pkg30000969carsarraylist.Car.(Car.java:46)
>       at pkg30000969carsarraylist.Car.(Car.java:46)

Comment: Deserializing a file depends directly on "how and what you serialized in that file". So to judge why you are encountering such this exception I need your serializing code. Please let me know how you serialized the array list.

Comment: Could you please share the code of the Car class

Comment: Could you share the code of the `Car` class? And also indicate lines 29 and 46 of `Car.java`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to see the [basics of serialization and deserialization](https://dzone.com/articles/serialization-amp-de-serialization-in-java)

Identified following issues with your code.

1. Since you are serializing Car data, Car class should implements `Serializable` interface

```java
public class Car implements Serializable {

    private String make;
    private String model;
    private String year;
    private String odometer;

    public Car(){}

    public Car(String year, String odometer, String make, String model)
    {
        this.make = make;
        this.model = model;
        this.year = year;
        this.odometer = odometer;
    }
}
```

2. Since you are adding List of cars to the file, while deserializing it, it will be List of cars and not Car, so casting with Car will fail
   change
   `cars = (Car)in.readObject();`
   to
   `ArrayList<Car> cars = (ArrayList<Car>) in.readObject();`
3. Constructor arguments are in out of order
   `public Car(String year, String odometer, String make, String model)`
   vs
   `cars.add(new Car(newMake, newModel, newYear, newOdometer));`
   so your mapping will be
   newMake --> year,
   newModel --> odometer,
   newYear --> make,
   newOdometer --> model

So finally working code is

```java
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class JavaBinaryFile {

    static ArrayList<Car> cars = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        addCar();
        saveFile();
        openFile();
    }

    public static void addCar() {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("What is the make of the car?");
        String newMake = scan.next();
        System.out.println("What is the model of the car?");
        String newModel = scan.next();
        System.out.println("What year was the car produced?");
        String newYear = scan.next();
        System.out.println("How far has this car traveled?");
        String newOdometer = scan.next();
        cars.add(new Car(newMake, newModel, newYear, newOdometer));
    }

    public static void openFile() {
        try {
            FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream("testSave.plzwork");
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
            try {
                ArrayList<Car> cars = (ArrayList<Car>) in.readObject();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Car.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            in.close();
            fileIn.close();
        } catch (IOException i) {
            i.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void saveFile() {
        try {
            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("testSave.plzwork");
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
            out.writeObject(cars);
            out.close();
            fileOut.close();
            System.out.println("Serialized data is saved");
        } catch (IOException i) {
            i.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```